# Show all points (airports) in featured country only

Tags: qgis, expression, rule-based

I need to generate maps showing all airports located in a featured country. My airport shapefile has over 8000 points, so I need to remove those that are irrelevant.

Example: When Sweden is featured, only the airports located in Sweden will show on the map.

I need to generate a rule stating that if the airport is located in the featured country then show, if not don’t show.

My airport shapefile and country shapefile have a matching column named “country_name”.

Comment: What do you mean by "Sweden is featured"? Do you want to print several country maps, is that it?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto i need to generate a printed map for every country. I will need to export 250 maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***I GOT IT!***

My featured country layer and airports shared a similar column and value "**ISO_CODE**".

- My featured country layer rule is: **$id =  $atlasfeatureid**
- The airports layer rule is: **attribute( $atlasfeature, 'ISO_CODE')  =   attribute($currentfeature, 'ISO_CODE')**

When you go to composer and set the active country layer as the "coverage layer" everything work!

Thanks for the help everyone, much appreciated!

Comment: uhmm... thats pretty much my answer.

Comment: BTW, in the second rule, you do not need to use attribute function, you can directly use the "ISO_CODE" field since you are inside the airport layer. That is: attribute( $atlasfeature, 'ISO_CODE') = "ISO_CODE"

Answer (score 3):

What you seek, can be easily done using the atlas features in the print composer. No need for clippings or filters. Specially if done one by one...

- Create a map layout according to your needs;
- Add, at least, one map item;
- In the atlas generation, use the country shape as your coverage layer.
- At the map item select the controlled by atlas, and set a value for the margin. The default 10% normally does the job;

At this point, using the atlas preview at the top of the print composer window, you should be able to go trough the 200 different maps, centred in each country of your country layer. All features will look the same tho...

Back in the QGIS main window:

- In the airport layer, use rule based symbology to set the following rule `within($geometry, $atlasgeometry)`

This way only the airport inside the atlas feature (a country) will be rendered.

Since you have a corresponding column in both layers, you can instead use an expression like this:

```
"country_name" = attribute($atlasfeature,'country_name')
```

Depending on the complexity of your geometries, this last rule might be faster than the first one.

This would answer your question...

**EXTRA**

...but I guess you can do a bit more. Probably you would like to somehow highlight the the "featured" country. The recipe is the same. In the Country layer you can set a rule like this:

```
$id = $atlasfeatureid
```

And give it a style. You can also draw other countries with a different style adding an `ELSE` rule to set another style for the rest of the countries.

Comment: Nice. This needs to get some more votes to move it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The geoprocessing tool you are looking for is the clip tool. This [guide](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/693) should help you, as the data you are using (airport points and country polygons) is vector data.

In short, you want to go here:

Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip.

Comment: This is a workable alternate approach, but I dislike the idea of creating several smaller shapefiles to represent each country when the original shapefile can be visualized differently with fewer steps and no subsequent litter on disk.